# Integrating Visio exported XAML into Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, visio, xamlreader

It is possible to export Microsoft Visio drawings as a Website containing Silverlight content. This is described on this [blog-post](http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2009/08/visio-2010-save-as-silverlight.html).

The output of such an export are the following:

- xaml_1.xaml (contains the structure of the control)
- data.xml (contains all text content such as labels, etc)
- several java-script files
- *.htm pages with a Silverlight container
- other files such as *.css and images

I would like to integrate the exported XAML code into another existing Silverlight application. I found this [blog-post](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/09/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-60-how-to-load-a-control-straight-from-xaml.aspx) telling me how to load XAML code dynamically during runtime.

What I would like to know is how to "merge" the XAML-file and the data.xml and how I can get a reference to the items of the XAML code, in order to change certain texts...

Answer (score 1):

In the associated xaml js file (eg xaml_1.js) there's a handleMouseUp function that reads the shape ID from the (XAML) 'name' string and then calls OnShapeClick in frameset.js.  This method, which is common to all of the js-based Save as web output types, then calls other methods to populate the details table or retrieve hyperlinks found in data.xml.  If you have a look at the FindShapeXML function in frameset.js you'll see that it gets the appropriate data based on the page and shape IDs (note that shape IDs are unique to a page as per Visio itself).

In terms of creating data-bound or dynamic shape text, one workaround for the glyphs issue that @slfan highlights is prevent the text from being output.  For example, prior to running Save As Web in Visio, you could loop through all of the shapes and set their *HideText* ShapeSheet cell to true.  This will prevent all of the glyphs xaml being generated and you'll still have access to the text string in data.xml.  I guess you wouldn't then benefit from the correct font scaling, but it depends on your scenario.  If it was really important to get the scale right then you could parse the RenderTransform attribute (which is described in attribute syntax rather than property element syntax) of the glyph elements.

Glyphs are there (I'm guessing) because it mirrors how Visio works in the application ie in Visio you can select individual characters within a shape's text and apply different fonts and formatting, but if you don't need that, I'd be tempted to ditch the glyphs collection and just use a TextBlock as @slfan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to tweak the generated XAML a little bit. Unfortunately Visio generates glyphs for every single character. If you want to change the text at runtime, you will have to remove this glyphs and add the required controls (e.g. TextBlock) yourself.

You can load the XAML into Silverlight with XamlReader.Load. A good description you find here: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/09/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-60-how-to-load-a-control-straight-from-xaml.aspx.

All JavaScript and HTML files you can ignore, the XML-file you need to identify your controls. The ID's in the XML refer to the corresponding elements in the XAML-file.

Comment: So basically, I have to parse the XML file to get the IDs of the elements, where I have to inject new object (e.g. a TextBlock)?